# What is the point of calling constructor with implicit conversion instead of assignment operator after an object is initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class CBox
{
public:
    CBox(double lv = 1.0, double wv = 1.0, double hv = 1.0) :
        m_Length {lv}, m_Width {wv}, m_Height {hv}
    {
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;   
    }

    //CBox& operator=(double)
    //{
    //  cout << "Assignment operator called" << endl;
    //  return *this;
    //}

    double volume() const { return m_Length* m_Width* m_Height; }

private:
    double m_Length;
    double m_Width;
    double m_Height;
};

int main()
{
    CBox box {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}; // no need for initializer list, but put it anyway
    box = 2.0; // why is this calling constructor again ?!
    cout << box.volume() << endl; // prints 2
}
```

Note, that I intentionally commented out the overloaded assignment operator.

Executing this program results in following output:

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
2
```

I noticed, that even if `box` object has been initialized, the next statement is deliberately calling the constructor again. What is the point of that?

I know that this can prevented by the `explicit` keyword, so the constructor would be:

```
explicit CBox(double lv = 1.0, double wv = 1.0, double hv = 1.0) :
        m_Length {lv}, m_Width {wv}, m_Height {hv}
    {
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;   
    }
```

but I would rather expect it to affect constructs like:

```
CBox box = 2.0;
```

Of course, when I uncomment overloaded assignment operator, then it takes precedence over constructor.

Comment: I'll try to make question clearer. The point is that I don't get why `box = 2.0;` is even allowed to call the constructor. This is not object intialization, because it is _already_ intialized, by the previous statement.

Comment: What would you expect assignment to do, if there is no assignment operator that takes a double on the RHS?

Comment: The second constructor is called for *different*  temporary object. Then this temporary object is being assigned to first object, and then temporary object is destroyed.

Comment: Second constructor is constructor of temporary object that is used by implicitly defined assignment operator of CBox class: CBox &operator=(const CBox &other);.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I would rather expect to throw an error, because of mismatched assignment, than messing with the constructor for second time with the same object (but I see now it's not actually the same).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Nothing is messing with a constructor for a second time with the same object. An object can only be initialized once.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I see. It's because of implicit assignment operator, that creates its own object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no implicit `CBox::operator=(double)`, so `box = 2.0;` has to create a temporary `CBox` object.  It's equivalent to `box = CBox(2.0);`.

Making your constructor `explicit` disallows the implicit conversion from `double` to `CBox`, so no appropriate assignment operator exists, and you get a compile error.

Answer (score 6):

There is a great difference between

```
CBox box = 2.0
```

and

```
box = 2.0
```

The first is equivalent to

```
CBox box = CBox(2.0)
```

While the second is equivalent to

```
box.operator=(2.0)
```

Since your constructor's arguments have default values, this is equivalent to defining 3 different constructors:

```
CBox(double, double, double)
CBox(double, double) // the third arguments gets default value
CBox(double) // second and third arguments gets default values
```

So, calling the constructor explicitly with a single `double` will invoke your constructor and will give the second and third arguments default values. And now for the real mystery: why did calling the `operator=` eventually result in calling a constructor?

Since you don't have an explicitly defined `operator=`, the compiler will auto-generate an assignment operator that takes another `CBox` as its single parameter; this will make a copy of the argument.

When you try to assign anything into your `CBox` object the compiler will attempt to call `operator=(const CBox&)`; since you provide a `double` and not a `CBox`, the compiler will try to convert the double into a `CBox` in one of many possible ways:

1. through non-explicit constructor (the third one in your case)
2. through conversion operator (not relevant in this case)
3. probably some other ways I'm not familiar with.

So, eventually this code:

```
box = 2.0
```

will be translated to:

```
box.operator=(Cbox(2.0))
```